# How to upsert multiple object by array in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have an array with an objects from which for each object i need to find if some key exist then it should update or else insert. I have done this from for loop but problem is i have approximately 20L of data which need to be run through this every morning using cron scheduler.

My question is : Can I use some other way like i pass this array to a method for better performance ?

My approach :

```
const arr = [{id: 1, pre: 10, post: 15 , name: 'egg'},{id: 2, pre: 10, post: 15 , name: 'egg 2'},{id: 3, pre: 10, post: 15 , name: 'egg 3'},{id: 4, pre: 10, post: 15 , name: 'egg 4'}]

for(x = 0; x < arr.length ; x++) {
   await processed_.findByIdAndUpdate({id: arr[x].id}, { $set: arr[x] }, {upsert: true, new: true})
}
```

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: You should search for `bulkWrite`. Use it with `updateMany` and set `upsert` to true.

Comment: @Wyck I have write bulkWrite but it didnt upserting the data. can you please help me to write this query

Comment: Sure, show your bulkWrite code and report any errors that you got, and be sure to describe your expected results vs actual results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use [***`bulkWrite`***](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#db.collection.bulkwrite--) to make your code more performant. `bulkWrite` allows you to send multiple update or insert operations in a single request, thus reducing the number of requests sent to the database. A sample code will look like(untested code but you get the idea):

```js
const arr = [
  {id: 1, pre: 10, post: 15, name: 'egg'},
  {id: 2, pre: 10, post: 15, name: 'egg 2'},
  {id: 3, pre: 10, post: 15, name: 'egg 3'},
  {id: 4, pre: 10, post: 15, name: 'egg 4'},
// ... others
];

const bulkOps = arr.map(doc => ({
  updateOne: {
    filter: {id: doc.id},
    update: {$set: doc},
    upsert: true
  }
}));

await processed_.bulkWrite(bulkOps);
```

**NOTE(from the Docs you might want to take a look):**

> The number of operations in each group cannot exceed the value of the maxWriteBatchSize of the database. The default value of maxWriteBatchSize is 100,000. This value is shown in the hello.maxWriteBatchSize field.